# hostname and hostname -s differ

Tags: linux, hosts

My /etc/hostname has:

```
name.domain.net
```

Previously, it was:

```
old.domain2.net
```

If I do `hostame` I get `name.domain.net`. But doing `hostname -s` returns `old`.

According to the man page:

```
   -s, --short
          Display the short host name. This is the host name cut at the first dot.
```

Which is not what I get. I have even rebooted the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me on CentOS 5.7 and found out using strace. Btw what distro is it?

Your /etc/hosts probably still looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   old.domain2.net localhost localhost.localdomain
```

You should replace the FIRST entry there, which probably still points to the old name.

This might also be tuned by editing /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/host.conf, but probably not required.